# Kubernetes HPA based on container threads

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

I want to autoscale a pod based on how many threads a container uses, so:
if container threads > 10 then scale from 1 -> 2.
Is this possible?

CPU utilization as metric is not going to work unfortunately.

Haven't found anything on this yet

Comment: Kubernetes on its own doesn't track this as a metric, but if you have some other metric system that's connected back to HPA then it should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by David Maze, Kubernetes does not track this as a statistic on its own, however if you have another metric system that is linked to HPA, it should be doable.

1. Try to gather metrics on the number of threads used by the container using a monitoring tool such as Prometheus.
2. Create a custom auto scaling script that checks the thread count using the monitoring tool's API and triggers a scaling event if it reaches 10.
3. Scale pods using K8S HPA based on a defined metric.

Refer to the doc [User-defined metrics overview](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics) for more information.